# Excel - Selecting from cell A1 to AX, where X is read in cell B1

Tags: excel, formulas

I have an Excel with 2 worksheets, first will be dinamically filled with data, having a row with a combo box feeding from row A on the second worksheet.
The second worksheet will also be filled dinamically, where will be:
Row A:
some values of variable number
B1 - Number of values on Row A to considerate.

My question is - Im using Data Validation > List to define the values on the ws1rowA combo box, is it possible to range from A1 to A(value in B1) ?

So far tried this on Data Validation "source" field:
=Sheet2!$A$1:offset(Sheet2!$A$1,=Sheet2!$B$1,0,1,1)
but an error is returned

Comment: Are you doing this so that the dropdown list changes as the number of rows increases?  If so, you could just give the column a name, and refer to that in your Validation Box.  It will ignore the blank cells.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just use

```
=OFFSET(Sheet2!$A$1,0,0,Sheet2!$B$1,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use INDIRECT function for this.

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet2!$A$1:$A"&Sheet2!$B$1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my version of Excel "You cannot use references to other worksheets or workbooks for Data Validation criteria" but you can use named ranges that have a Workbook Scope, so name a range (eg DataValid) to apply to say the range as @Maxim Korneev and then for Data Validation in Sheet1 use a list whose Source: is =DataValid.